# Javascript Map Won't Return Array Value, for D3.js Chart

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, hashmap, undefined

I'm working on creating a graph that will show unemployment rates by county in the United States. It's based on Mike Bostock's County-level map [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606), and it looks like this:

[image]

It works by pulling data from a CSV, assigning that data to a Javascript Map, and using that to color the various counties with a d3 color scale. My CSV data looks like this:

```
county,area,rate2007,rate2008,rate2009,rate2010,rate2011,rate2012,rate2013,rate2014,rate2015,rate2016
01001,Autauga County,3.3,5.1,9.7,8.9,8.4,6.9,6.2,5.9,5.3,5.3
01003,Baldwin County,3.1,4.6,9.8,10.0,9.0,7.5,6.6,6.1,5.6,5.4
01005,Barbour County,6.3,8.8,14.3,12.3,11.5,11.5,10.2,10.6,8.8,8.6
01007,Bibb County,4.1,5.8,13.3,11.4,10.5,8.5,7.9,7.2,6.7,6.6
01009,Blount County,3.2,4.7,10.0,9.8,8.7,6.9,6.3,6.1,5.4,5.5
etc...
```

**Here's my issue:** I want to be able to change this data over time, and to do so must be able to include multiple values in my Map. However, I cannot get this to work. In attempting to "upgrade" my map, I tweak the code slightly to use an array as the value in the key-value pair in the Map:

```
d3.queue()
   .defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
   .defer(d3.csv, "unemploymentEdited.csv", function(d) {
        unemployment.set(d.county, [+d.rate2007, +d.rate2008]);
   }) // I use an array here to include multiple values.
   .await(ready);
```

When I log this to the console, my data is indeed formatted as I would expect:

[image]

However, I cannot use these values to color my paths correctly. When I use a relatively simple function to access the data from the Map, it logs this error to the console: "TypeError: unemployment.get(...) is undefined."

Even more strangely, when I log this same thing to the console *outside* of my "fill" attribute, I get the number I would expect, meaning I get the values inside my Map. Like if I write `console.log(unemployment.get(d.id)[0])` I get 4.6, or whatever the value is. **What am I doing wrong? Why does the "get" function return undefined, even though I can see that the data structure is not?**

Here's my full code:

```
var width = 960;
var height = 600;
var margin = {top: 50, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0}

var path = d3.geoPath(); // Geopath generator

var unemployment = new Map();
var color =  d3.scaleSequential()
        .domain([0.0,30.0])
        .interpolator(d3.interpolateInferno);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
  .style("background-color","lightgrey")

d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
    .defer(d3.csv, "unemploymentEdited.csv", function(d){
      unemployment.set(d.county, [+d.rate2007,+d.rate2008])
    })
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, us) {

  console.log(unemployment)

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
      .attr("transform",`translate(0,${margin.top})`)
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d){
      return color(unemployment.get(d.id)[0])
    })
    .attr("d", path)

}
```

Comment: As you have two different data sets (the TopoJSON and the CSV), which adds complexity, the best idea is creating a running code. In your case, try [Blockbuilder](http://blockbuilder.org/). Just copy/paste the code and upload the two data files, with the correct names and extensions. Also, it's important checking if `d.id` exactly matches `d.county`.

Comment: Here's the bl.ock (I do use blockbuilder, it's great). Same problem though. https://bl.ocks.org/KingOfCramers/raw/93fba8eb9f797c31fe4f1cab52a3ed32/5824f8b505c1a6d660939d5d4f183e37e03daa2f/

Comment: We cannot edit a bl.ock, that's why I suggested a blockbuilder. I'm having a look at it now.

Comment: Sorry, it's here: http://blockbuilder.org/KingOfCramers/93fba8eb9f797c31fe4f1cab52a3ed32

Comment: No worries, it's just a matter of changing `bl.ocks.org` to `blockbuilder.org` (normally). +1 for the well documented question, I wish they were always like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your `d3.map()` is correct, that's not the problem.

The problem is that your CSV doesn't have data for **all** counties. Therefore, sometimes, this...

```
unemployment.get(d.id)
```

... is `undefined`, which explains your error:

```
unemployment.get(d.id)[0] --> Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

**Solution**

Check for undefined:

```
.attr("fill", function(d){
    return unemployment.get(d.id) ? color(unemployment.get(d.id)[0]) : "#ccc";
})
```

Here, if `unemployment.get(d.id)` is undefined, the function will return `#ccc`. Change this according to the colour you want.

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/3adc7518e4423d816f6b6842ef48d27f/414e4b738dd4c2d8e91a9ca2fb8511dcec747b9c

Comment: Thank you! I will have to make sure to check for undefined in all my data in the future. Real-world data is more sloppy than what I am used to using while learning D3. Also, I checked out your visualizations on neocities, very cool stuff!  :)